# graphql query is embedded inside req.body

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, graphql

So I'm trying to move from REST to GraphQL but there's a minor thing that makes it a little bit harder is that queries e.g.

`www.example.com?test=test` the `query: { test: "test" }` is actually under `body: { query: { test: "test" } }` in GraphQL. So I was wondering if there was some middleware or something that could move this back out.

I'm using `body-parser` via

```
var bodyParser =
    require("body-parser")
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's a specific reason you want to validate and execute the GraphQL document yourself, you should probably use an existing library for that. Two of the more popular solutions for express:

```
//express-graphql
const graphqlHTTP = require('express-graphql');
const { makeExecutableSchema } = require('graphql-tools');

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});

app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
  schema,
  graphiql: true,
}));

app.listen(4000);

// apollo-server-express
const express = require('express');
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server-express');

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });

server.applyMiddleware({ app });

app.listen(4000);
```

You can also just use `apollo-server`, which runs apollo-server-express under the hood.

```
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server');

// pass in a schema
const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema
});

// or let Apollo make it for you
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});

server.listen()
```

None of these solutions require you to include `body-parser` and provide a ton of extra features out-of-the-box.

Comment: I've kind of rethought how to perform the resolvers. Because since I'm using express and was using REST, I was basically passing everything via `(req, res)` but having thought about it for a while, I should really do preliminary validation via another function, which then calls another function to actually execute read/writes onto my mongo db.